# Node.js app disappears from pm2 daemon after successful deployment from automatic git deployment in Jelastic

Tags: node.js, pm2, jelastic

I have been trying to deploy my node application from the automatic GIT deployment option in Jelastic.
Everytime I push the selected branch, the deployment start and then the post deployment hook script is called, launching my server using pm2.

The post deployment hook script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/ROOT/

npm install
npm run build
pm2 reload app.config.js --env production
```

app.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'app',
    script: './build/app.js',
    instances: 1,
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'dev'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'prod'
    }
  }],
};
```

Jelastic deployment log:

```
[INFO] Thu Sep 12 15:37:03 UTC 2019 Applying Post-deploy hook for ROOT 

audited 829 packages in 4.926s
found 0 vulnerabilities


> com.irealite.oceanopolis@1.0.0 build /home/jelastic/ROOT
> tsc

[PM2] Applying action reloadProcessId on app [app](ids: [ 0 ])
[PM2] [app](0) ✓
[INFO] Post-deploy hook applied successfully
```

As you can see, the app is started and nothing went wrong. I even manage to see the app using `pm2 status` but after 10 seconds, it disappeared.

The strangest thing is that, when I manually call the deployment from the git repository, the same script is called, resulting in the same logs, but this time the node.js app stays online.

## tl;dr

My post deploy hook script launches my server successfully but my app disappear after a few seconds when the hook is automatically called from a change on the remote repository (don't disappear when called manually)

Comment: @jelastic any clue ?

Comment: Since it's really hard to find out the reason of such behavior from the information provided it would be better to address this question to your hosting provider so we were able to take a closer look together.

Comment: @jelastic I just created a ticket in my hosting service. Thank you